# Using AccessCHK with pipe

Tags: security, sysinternals

Can anyone post an example of using accesschk with \pipe.
I'm running process with -s param and getting a lot of files listed, but only folders are needed.
Tried to run with *findstr /vi ".[a-z]$", but no success
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it :-)
accesschk -s -d  Z:
**-s** means recursive, **-d** means no files (Only process directories or top-level keys)